# Variable references non-existent resource Build.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am using Eclipse Kepler and I am trying to execute my build script.

When I run a task, I get an Ant error that says

> Variable references non-existent resource :
>   ${workspace_loc:/MyProject_JAVA/dev-new/build.xml}.

The problem is this path is wrong.  It should be :

> /MyProject_JAVA/dev/dev-new/build.xml.

I can go into External Tools and change the config for this one build, but if I try to run the task again, I get the same error.

How do I change where Ant thinks the build file is?

Answer (score 7):

I met same problem , fortunately I solved it. 
Go into preferences of Eclipse, and edit Ant - Runtime - Classpath. 
You will find reason, and delete the error configured entry.

---

[image: Error Pic]

---

[image: Solve Pic]

Answer (score 1):

I think your closing curly brace is misplaced and I'm not sure the colon is necessary. Try:
`${workspace_loc}/MyProject_JAVA/dev-new/build.xml`

EDIT: I'm assuming you are using this in your Ant Build external configuration's "Main" tab, in the "Base Directory" field.

EDIT 2: Actually, as I look at your description closer, it appears the MyProject_JAVA folder exists outside of the workspace. Is that correct? If so, try using ${project_loc} instead.

Comment: The ${workspace_loc:path} syntax is valid - see http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-exttools.htm

Comment: So is the syntax I proposed & the supplied link mentions the two slightly different syntaxes can produce different results.

Comment: ${workspace_loc:path} will deal with a project with linked files outside of the workspace whereas ${workspace_loc}path will not.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to **billni's** answer, you may have an incorrectly defined Ant classpath.

Find the bad path within *Window > Preferences > Ant > Runtime > Entries*

**I have 3 entry types:**

- Ant Home Entries
- Global Entries
- Contributed Entries

For my situation, the bad path was in > **Global Entries**

To fix this, remove the bad path by selecting > **Remove**

Add the new and correct path by either using > **Add JARs...** or > **Add External JARs...**

- **Add JARs...** > allows you to add archives from your package explorer to your build path.
- **Add External JARs...** > allows you to add archives from your local file system to your build path.

Assuming your path is correct, and that there are no other errors, your build should now work!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, after I renamed the project using "Refactor"-->"Rename..." on a project for which I use an Ant builder.
I had to

- open the project's Properties
- go to "Builders"
- select the Ant builder
- click "Edit..." on the right hand-side
- in the Edit Configuration dialog, in the "Main" tab, the "Buildfile:" field was pointing to a path containing the old project name. I changed it to the new project name and it worked.