# Eclipse Build file has non existent resource

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have imported a java servlet project to maintain into Eclipse (Helios) and made my amendments.  But when I drag the Build.xml file to the Ant view and attempt to build the project I receive the error;

"Variable references non-existent resource: ${workspace_loc:/projectname/lib/jsch-0.1.50.jar}"

The only place I can find this resource is going to this location in Eclipse; Window >> Preferences >> Ant >> Runtime.  Then on the Classpath tab it is under the "Global Entries"

How do I resolve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this resolved and the Servlet is working as desired and building fine.  I used this other Stackoverflow as a guide as it was quite similar.  I deleted the reference as this link says and then referenced the Jsch-0.1.50.jar in the tomcat\lib folder.  I was then able to build the app and tests so far on the war file have been successful.

[Variable references non-existent resource Build.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160620/variable-references-non-existent-resource) 
-build-xml