# Renaming file I got this error: !MESSAGE Variable references non-existent resource

Tags: python, eclipse, resources, liclipse

I'm making a game in Python (with Pygame) using LiClipse (based on Eclipse). My main file which executes everything is called "**prueba.py**". I've renamed it to "**Main.py**" and then trying to run the project I've got this error:

> !MESSAGE Variable references non-existent resource :
>   ${workspace_loc:MyGame/prueba.py}

Is there any file where I can change the file or something like that? Anyway, how can I solve it? I've tried many solutions from google and stackoverflow (such as this [Variable references non-existent resource Build.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160620/variable-references-non-existent-resource-build-xml)) but they didn't work or didn't apply to my problem.

Comment: Most likely something in the 'Run Configuration' for the project (look in 'Run > Run Configurations').

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks, it solved the problem. If you post it as solution I will mark it as accepted! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably the Run Configuration for the project.

Look in 'Run > Run Configurations' for your project and check the variables.